# Which is better: multiple web socket endpoints or single web socket endpoint in Java EE7

Tags: websocket, java-ee-7

Java EE 7 allows you to create new endpoints very easily through annotations.  However, I was wondering is having multiple endpoints one to handle each message type a good idea or should I have just one endpoint facade for everything?

I am leaning towards having one single end-point facade based on the theory that each endpoint creates a new socket connection to the client.  However, that theory could be incorrect and Web Socket may be implemented so that it will use just one TCP/IP socket connection regardless of how many web socket end points are connected so long as they connect to the same host:port.

I am asking specifically for Java EE 7, as there may be other web socket server implementations that may do things differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only valid answer here is the latter option - having multiple endpoints.

See [WebSocket spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) chaper 2.1.3:

> The API limits the registration of MessageHandlers per Session to be one MessageHandler per native websocket message type. [WSC 2.1.3-1] In other words, the developer can only register at most one Mes- sageHandler for incoming text messages, one MessageHandler for incoming binary messages, and one MessageHandler for incoming pong messages. The websocket implementation must generate an error if this restriction is violated [WSC 2.1.3-2].

As for using or not using multiple TCP connections - AFAIK currently there will be new connection for every client and there is no easy way how you can force anything else. [WebSocket multiplexing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-websocket-multiplexing-11) should solve it, but I don't think any WebSocket API implementation support it (I might be wrong..)

Comment: This actually answers the question I had posed above because of the ambiguity of the word message types.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm kind of slow, so, if I use multiple endpoints, there will be just one connection open per client or a connection per endpoint?

Comment: connection per endpoint. There was a rfc draft for multiplexing, but it was never finished (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-websocket-multiplexing-11).

Answer (score 9):

Just noticed an ambiguity on my question re: message types.  When I say message types I meant different kinds of application messages not native message types such as "binary" or "text".  As such I marked @PavelBucek answer as the accepted one.

However, I did try an experiment with Glassfish and having two end points.  My suspicions were correct and that there is a TCP connection established per connected endpoint.  This would cause more load on the server side if there is more than one websocket endpoint being used on a single page.

As such I concluded that there should be only one endpoint to handle the application messages provided that everything is a single native type.

This would mean that the application needs to do the dispatching rather than relying on some higher level API to do it for us.