# Calling different Java services with the same Websocket session

Tags: java, javascript, session, websocket

I've defined a websocket in JavaScript like so:

> var waitAndSend = "ws://localhost:8080/WebSocket/firstService"

And call with `websocket.send(message);`

This calls a service defined in Java like so:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/firstService")
public class FirstService {
      //...@OnOpen omitted...
      @OnMessage
        public void onMessage (Session peer) {
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

Which is all fine and dandy but I'd like to call a **different** service from the same browser session. And I'd like that Java webservice to have access to the same Websocket session on the server side.

I attempted this by defining a another websocket in the JavaScript and Java but then realised that I'd need to call the new services `@onOpen` method which would start a 2nd session. So how do I get multiple services to operate under the same session?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280455/which-is-better-multiple-web-socket-endpoints-or-single-web-socket-endpoint-in The API limits the registration of `MessageHandlers` per `Session` to be one `MessageHandler` per native websocket message type. [WSC 2.1.3-1] In other words, the developer can only register at most one `MessageHandler` for incoming text messages, one `MessageHandler` for incoming binary messages, and one `MessageHandler` for incoming pong messages. The websocket implementation must generate an error if this restriction is violated [WSC 2.1.3-2].

Comment: You could switch on the payload of your message and then execute the appropriate code, with an abstraction like `STOMP` the code-smell is nicely hidden. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/